# Default Security Group Settings on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

My current settings are here:

[image]

I understand the HTTP and the SSH lines but do I need the first three lines for icmp, tcp and udp? I must have set this up a couple years ago but I am looking to get it right this time and use EC2 properly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three lines allows to enable the communications on all ports between EC2 instances which have started behind your default Security Group.

Comment: So, I should keep them there if I want someday to have a web/app server on a separate instance than my DB right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise your web app server can not connect with your DB.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I am unable to ping the EC2 instance though it serves up HTTP and I can ssh to it just fine. What's the best way to enable ping - change the icmp protocol's source to 0.0.0.0/0 - or do I do that for the tcp protocol?

Comment: Yes, for enable ping, change or add the icmp protocol's source to 0.0.0.0/0. Source to 0.0.0.0/0 allows to authorize ping from all IP.